# How to stop Firefox searching Amazon and other "Top Sites"

Tags: firefox, browser, search, firefox-quantum

Today I discovered a Firefox feature that allows you to search within particular sites by prepending the search term with an `@`:

[image]

This seems like an implementation of the [similar Chrome behaviour](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=firefox+omnibar), except that it only applies to the listed sites.

I also now realise that this feature is what was responsible for my occasionally landing on Amazon when I typed a search term too fast into the address bar. For this reason I find these shortcuts to be more trouble than they're worth, especially since there's already another implementation of the feature [that allows you to specify any site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar) to be searched.

However, I haven't been able to find any official documentation on this at all, let alone instructions for disabling the feature, and following the instructions [here](https://techdows.com/2018/10/firefox-search-shortcuts-rolling-out-to-us.html) to disable the `browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.improvesearch.topSiteSearchShortcuts` preference doesn't seem to make any difference, even after a restart.

How exactly do I disable this feature?

Answer (score 3):

#### How exactly do I disable this feature?

1. Go to `About:Preferences#Search`
2. Remove the entries you don't want from the "One-Click Search Engines" section

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It slipped my mind to mention, but I want to be able to do this without removing the search bar's search engines, as it can be useful to explicitly search those sites when I need to. I just don't want that behaviour in my address bar when I need to search, as it can often get in the way.